# xCode NSInvalid Argument Exception from PHP Echo

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to write a newsfeed system that is based from a `MySQL` database, I am using `PHP` to echo the article, however I am constantly finding new special characters that are causing

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]: nil argument'
```

Is there any way in `PHP` or `Xcode` to prevent, I have used replace in `PHP` and have a large list of characters however it works for a little while until someone adds new articles with new characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try php `[utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) php function to encode the special characters